# configure method from startup is not hitting in .net core 6

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2022, kestrel-http-server, asp.net-core-6.0

We are using GIT with Azure DevOps for version control. and I am using Visual Studio 2022 and .Net 6.

My application is not hitting the configure method from the startup.cs file after pulling the latest changes. That's why my localhost is not running and Swagger is not launching.

I tried below approaches

1. deleted .vs folder
2. deleted bin, obj files
3. restarted visual studio in administrator mode.
4. rebuild solution again

but it is not working.

Any assistance would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your IDE running? What do you see in logs or output window? Also you don't need configure method in .Net 6. Please look up the relevant migration guide here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#new-hosting-model

Comment: @ParthSekar I can see below in output window. 'ServiceHost.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.10\System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

The thread 0x675c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x68d8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4320 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xf3c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x6150 has exited with code 0 (0x0).